# My volume is greyed out with a (/) on it

Tags: snow-leopard, sound-volume

I am running Mac OS X 10.6.8.

The output of `sudo killall coreaudiod` and `sudo osascript -e "set Volume 5"`:

```
Last login: Fri Nov 25 09:13:21 on ttys000
Daniel-Jensens-MacBook:~ danieljensen$ sudo killall coreaudiod
Daniel-Jensens-MacBook:~ danieljensen$ sudo osascript -e "set Volume 5"
2016-11-25 09:14:30.662 osascript[173:e07] Error loading /Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Unit Types:  dlopen(/Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Unit Types, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Unit Types: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
osascript: OpenScripting.framework - scripting addition "/Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax" declares no loadable handlers.
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The output device has a physical detector for mini TOSLINK plug. I believe it's stuck (dirt), so just try to insert and remove several times a 3.5mm headphone to unblock it.

Answer (score 1):

‘Optical digital-out port’ shown in System Preferences indicates that the computer believes something is plugged in to the audio out on your computer. Try plugging in headphones then disconnecting them, or otherwise clean the port.

Comment: no thats not it it is also flashing red from inside

Comment: @user6353435 It's flashing red *because* it thinks there's an optical digital out connected — that's the signal.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work

Comment: ya know what i'll just reinstall snow leopard